# Scraping code returning no results under the class "post_block hentry with_rep"

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am very new in web scraping and trying to scrap an example [forum](http://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=249843). I am using the following code in scrapy:
items.py file

```
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field

 class StackoverflowItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    pass
```

and test.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "stackspider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.toytowngermany.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=249843"]

    def parse(self,response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "post_block hentry  with_rep")] /div[@class="post_wrap"]')
       for sites in sites:
           title = sites.select('div[@class="post_body"]/div[@class="post entry-content"]/text()').extract()
       print title
```

This is just an example code and I would like to scrape all the information under the class "post_block hentry  with_rep". For testing, I tried running the code above but it is not giving any results. Can you please suggest what mistake I am making in the xpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the `post_body` div is not a direct child of the `post_block` child - there is another div in between.

Try something like this:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "stackspider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.toytowngermany.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=249843"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "post_block hentry  with_rep")]/div[@class="post_wrap"]')
        for site in sites:
            title = site.xpath('div/div[@class="post_body"]/div[@class="post entry-content"]/text()').extract()
            print(title)
```

i.e. just add an extra `div/` to the start of the second path selector. Alternatively, you could add `.//` which would allow any arbitrary elements in the hierarchy before the `post_body` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

This is because  When you are selecting using hxs you missed a `"/"` at the end as the div hierarchy will be disrupted  :

```
sites = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "post_block hentry  with_rep")] /div[@class="post_wrap"]/')
```

or second option inclue it at the beginning of your select

```
 title = sites.select('//div[@class="post_body"]/div[@class="post entry-content"]/text()').extract()
```

hope one of the two methods sole your query :)